# Calculate degree of vertices in an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

fp = open('direct.csv')

# counts how many times each pair worked together
pairs = {}

# each element of `project` is a person
for project in (p[:-1].split(',') for p in fp):
    project.sort()

    # someone is alone here
    if len(project) == 1:
        continue

    # iterate over each pair 
    for i in range(len(project)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(project)):
            pair = (project[i], project[j])
            # increase `pairs` counter
            pairs[pair] = pairs.get(pair, 0) + 1

from pprint import pprint
pprint(pairs)
```

"direct.csv" is a matrix file i got from CAIDA Network Topology (2x4000) matrix file look like this:
    10010   2516;
    10010   37907;
    10010   55385;
    10010   55387;
    10010   58650;
    10010   7690;
    10010   9351;
    10010   9615;
    10010   9622;
    10010   9990;
    10012   23720;
    10013   4686;
    10015   10002;
    10015   17945;
    10015   18264;
    10015   2512;
    10015   9351;
    10015   9997;
I have to make an adjacency matrix out of this but when i have to do so i end up with a 2gb worth of file and i can not do anything about that so i use this code so python can process all of the data and do something with it (take all of the zeros out from adjacency matrix)

My question is, is it possible to know how many connection does one AS has. for example 10010 =7; 10015=5 with a highest-lowest order

Comment: So... what question are you asking?

Comment: Did you mean to use an adjacency matrix? Because what you have is not an adjacency matrix.

Comment: direct.csv is a 2 column matrix with 40000 lines so when i use an adjacency matrix it was too big so i use this program to put them as pairs. What I want to ask is how can I know ho many times does a have a connection with any. A B;A C; A D; B E
--> Connection of A=3
Connection of B = 2

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list